# How can I get rid of this mod on CoD: World at War PS3?

Tags: ps3, mods, call-of-duty-world-at-war

I was playing online Team Deathmach on Call Of Duty World at War, and someone 'modded' me and my game was patched. On the screen, it popped up with

> Please enjoy this patch

and the next thing I knew my game was modded.

Now everytime I enter a match I get these for different class options which are all just my PSN name in various colors:

[image: The 'choose class' screen]

As you can see there are 4 modded class options. I don't like it and want to get rid of it. How can I reset my game or otherwise remove this mod?

Comment: Someone modded you...?

Comment: Yeah someone in the game was modding and it said on my screen "please enjoy this patch" and my game was modded

Comment: @TimmyJim - Not that farfetched. I somehow managed to join a modded server back in MW2 days which, upon the first award of experience, finished all challenges, levelled me up to the max level, and unlocked all the weapons and skins. I was none too impressed. :-/

Comment: @Robotnik I remember once in MW2 on 360, there's was a bug (at least I thought it was a bug, but perhaps it was a mod) that spread like wild fire that allowed you to shoot anything as a machine gun (such as the AC-130s giant shell and grenade launchers).  I didn't think it was really possible to spread mods on consoles like this.

Comment: Deontray, what happens if you attempt to create a class?  Do you have the ability to delete them and make a new one?

Comment: @TimmyJim - Yeah I have no idea how it's done, I've also heard of 'low gravity' matches occurring and a bunch of other quirks.

Comment: @Deontray - What happens if you change weapons or the name of the class?

Comment: I can changed the name of a custom class just fine, though I don't know how to delete a class completely.

Comment: Have you uninstalled the game and reinstalled it?

Comment: I haven't tried it. How would you do this on PS3? Also, update. I've now been completely hacked and my cod profile was deranked from level 16 to level 1 and my xp is -9988895. I can't play online multiplayer at ALL. Contacting Activision about this

Comment: @Deontray - what did Activision have to say?

Answer (score 1):

Well there honestly is not much you can do. Activision support will do NOTHING AT ALL, and they will never do anything for this game. When you get infected like you did then closing the game or turning off your console usually does the trick, if it remains after than you can try changing the names of custom classes and seeing if they are still editable. Prestiging will also reset your custom classes. If the modder deranks you to level -1, your only option is to install mods yourself and level yourself up in a private match or to get a friend or modder to level your account up in a private match.

The game has been in a modder-infested state for a while, it is at its worst on PS3 (lowest player population). If you really want to play multiplayer your best bet is PC, I have only ever seen a single cheater on PC as it uses players own servers, which have good anti-cheat and active moderators.

Answer (score -2):

Meh easy fix man , just chanhe the name of the class done

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to do this and give some insight on why this helps?